# Package not found even though the jar is in WEB-INF/lib

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, netbeans, ant

I have a Tomcat 8 web project that I started in Netbeans.
In Netbeans I setup some Global Libraries that I then added to the project.
Building the project in Netbeans works perfectly.

The problem is when I try to build on a Unix platform using Ant.
I use the build.xml file automatically generated by Netbeans, the only difference is that I now have to specify where these "Global" libraries are, I do this as so:

```
ant -Dlibs.spring-framework-4.0.6.classpath="../libs/spring-framework-4.0.6.RELEASE" clean dist
```

This however results in these kinds of errors:

```
error: package org.springframework.beans.factory does not exist
```

If I go and look inside the build folder in web/WEB-INF/lib, the jar is there and if I look inside it I do find the org.springframework.beans.factory class.

If I run ant in debug mode it clearly states that is copying over the libs:

```
[copy] Copying /libs/spring-framework-4.0.6.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar to /App/build/web/WEB-INF/lib/spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar
```

As I understand it, the WEB-INF/lib directory is on the classpath by default. Is this not what happens and do I need to specifically tell it to add this directory to the classpath?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution myself, it turns out I have to specifically reference each and every jar, it is not enough to reference the directory.

So this:

```
ant -Dlibs.spring-framework-4.0.6.classpath="../libs/spring-framework-4.0.6.RELEASE" clean dist
```

Should have been this:

```
ant -Dlibs.spring-framework-4.0.6.classpath="../libs/spring-framework-4.0.6.RELEASE/spring-aop-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:../libs/spring-framework-4.0.6.RELEASE/spring-aspects-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:../libs/spring-framework-4.0.6.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:../libs/spring-framework-4.0.6.RELEASE/spring-context-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:../libs/spring-framework-4.0.6.RELEASE/spring-context-support-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:../libs/spring-framework-4.0.6.RELEASE/spring-core-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:../libs/spring-framework-4.0.6.RELEASE/spring-expression-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:../libs/spring-framework-4.0.6.RELEASE/spring-framework-bom-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:../libs/spring-framework-4.0.6.RELEASE/spring-instrument-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:../libs/spring-framework-4.0.6.RELEASE/spring-instrument-tomcat-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:../libs/spring-framework-4.0.6.RELEASE/spring-jdbc-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:../libs/spring-framework-4.0.6.RELEASE/spring-jms-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:../libs/spring-framework-4.0.6.RELEASE/spring-messaging-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:../libs/spring-framework-4.0.6.RELEASE/spring-orm-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:../libs/spring-framework-4.0.6.RELEASE/spring-oxm-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:../libs/spring-framework-4.0.6.RELEASE/spring-test-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:../libs/spring-framework-4.0.6.RELEASE/spring-tx-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:../libs/spring-framework-4.0.6.RELEASE/spring-web-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:../libs/spring-framework-4.0.6.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:../libs/spring-framework-4.0.6.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-portlet-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:../libs/spring-framework-4.0.6.RELEASE/spring-websocket-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar"  clean dist
```